# dig and dig -x are answering different

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver

I don't want the name provider to manage my records. I want to handle it myself.
So I installed bind9 and made some configurations reading some articles and following some examples. bind didn't show any error after I created/edited the required files but;

When I write

`dig www.foo.com, I see the IP of the advertisement page of my name provider.

But when I write

```
dig -x server_ip_address; I see the name I purchased.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Can't a server be the nameserver of it's own? Is it a must to configure the records from the company I bought the name from?

*By the way, I realised that, my previous question was not clear, I deleted it, and asking the same question in a different way.*

Comment: I didn't say I am pro, why theese down votes?  what is wrong with the question?

Comment: It's easy to tell you're not a pro. Unfortunately, if you read the [faq], you will see that this site is **only** for pros.

Comment: So I have to continue with forums around. I see ;-)

Comment: No, read faq and now can say, this question obeys the rules. I needed pro help and had a question answerable.

Comment: This isn't a place for people that aren't pros to get help from pros. It's a site for pros to get help from other pros.

Comment: Tell us the domain name and the IP in question and maybe we can tell you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, a server can't be simply a name server on it's own, at least not for public domains, For this to work, your registrar has to delegate this to your server. Until this happens, the registrar's DNS servers will answer all queries for your domain.

Usually, it's a pretty bad idea anyway to try to run your own DNS server unless you have a specific reason to so. DNS is difficult to get right but really important for all kind of things, so you should leave this to people who know this subject.

Comment: > Usually, it's a pretty bad idea anyway to try to run your own DNS server
**Usually, it is pretty bad idea to run own server.**

Comment: @eicto: What are you trying to say?

Comment: I trying to say that it is incorrect. Nothing hard to control own dns and nothing hard to run it on own server, it just not needed in most cases

Comment: I smell ego here. Dont take personel but, when i started high school i knew OOP. My family took me to courses, but the teacher rejected me saying not a good idea and I am a software engineer now. Hopefully I will be able to learn much more about servers too.

Comment: @erdemkeren this is a site for **professionals**. He answered your question in the first paragraph and then gave you sound professional advice in the second paragraph. I'm not sure what your problem with his answer is. I came here to say the same thing, but saw there was already an answer that covered it.

Comment: @MDMarra you mixed the person i wrote, i think.